# Android: How to get the selected item in listview using cursor?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am very new to Android.

Can anybody tell me how can I get the selected item from the `ListView` when the data is coming from a `Cursor`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created a `ListActivity` (which has a `ListView` in it), the `onListItemClick()`-method is called every time a entry in the list is clicked. This method has a parameter `long id` which contains the ID of your selected Item.

The idea behind this is, that every entry in your SQLite Database has a unique ID (using `auto_increment`). If you set your `ListActivity` up with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you'll need to have a column named `_id` (if you have a ID-column with another name, use the `AS`-function). This column is automatically used to determine which ID the clicked entry has.

So lets say one of your entry's has the ID `12` and this ID is in the column `_id`. If you select this entry from your `ListView`, the `onListItemClick()`-method's `id`-parameter will contain the value `12`.

This is the easiest way if you're using a Database for your content (like in a Notebook).

Answer (score 1):

You set an `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView` using the `setOnItemClickListener` method.

Within that method you have the selected position and you can call your adapter's `getItem` method for that position.

You should probably override `getItem` in your adapter to return a properly constructed object from your domain.

Comment: Can you please past the code of overriding `getItem` method please?